# Unable to encode compound document JSON:API error

Tags: php, laravel, json-api

Struggling with an newbee issue. When I hit an endpoint that is registered under the JSONAPIRoute facade, I get an error (attached).

This is what I have in my routes:

```
JsonApiRoute::server('v1')
    ->prefix('v1')
    ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1') 
    ->resources(function ($server) {
        $server->resource('posts');
    });
```

This is what I have in my PostController:
class PostController extends Controller
{

```
use Actions\FetchMany;
use Actions\FetchOne;
use Actions\Store;
use Actions\Update;
use Actions\Destroy;
use Actions\FetchRelated;
use Actions\FetchRelationship;
use Actions\UpdateRelationship;
use Actions\AttachRelationship;
use Actions\DetachRelationship;
```

}

I edited the FetchOne Action to go a GET request to a third party API:

trait FetchOne
{

```
/**
 * Fetch zero to one JSON API resource by id.
 *
 * @param Route $route
 * @param StoreContract $store
 * @return Responsable|Response
 */
public function retrieveData(Request $request){
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'api-key' => '****',
    ])->get('https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-pkrpq/endpoint/getRandom');
    return response()->json(['status'=> true,'data'=> json_decode($response->body()), 'Message'=>'Successfully retrieved'], 200);
}
```

}

This is the full trace of my error:

```
{
    "message": "Unable to encode compound document. See previous exception for cause of failure.",
    "exception": "LogicException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel-json-api\\encoder-neomerx\\src\\Document.php",
    "line": 201,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel-json-api\\core\\src\\Core\\Responses\\Internal\\ResourceCollectionResponse.php",
            "line": 88,
            "function": "toJson",
            "class": "LaravelJsonApi\\Encoder\\Neomerx\\Document",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel-json-api\\core\\src\\Core\\Responses\\DataResponse.php",
            "line": 120,
            "function": "toResponse",
            "class": "LaravelJsonApi\\Core\\Responses\\Internal\\ResourceCollectionResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 888,
            "function": "toResponse",
            "class": "LaravelJsonApi\\Core\\Responses\\DataResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 875,
            "function": "toResponse",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 797,
            "function": "prepareResponse",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel-json-api\\laravel\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\BootJsonApi.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "LaravelJsonApi\\Laravel\\Http\\Middleware\\BootJsonApi",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 126,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 92,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 797,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 776,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 740,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 729,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 200,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 39,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 175,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 144,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 51,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\jasmi\\newproject\\testing\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php",
            "line": 16,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Unable to encode compound document. See previous exception for cause of failure." — So what does the previous exception say?

Comment: @Quentin I added the full trace I get on Postman to the question, there is nothing else I am getting. The previous error was a 401 - which had to do with authentication. I changed my policies to enable all users to view all models resolving that initial error

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved? I am also running into a similar issue.